# Is there a word for a portion of information presented at once?

Tags: single-word-requests

A webpage chooses to present information a bit at a time, rather than all at once, like this: http://mathinbrief.com/algebra/arithmetic-series. So the user is invited to consider an initial chunk of information, then to press a button to see more. After that, the user might press an additional button to add more information to the page.

My question is -- is there a natural name for those pieces of information? Ideally, it would convey they idea that they are relatively small chunks.

A couple of sentences:

A page on this site consists of multiple xxxxx, which will be presented to the user one at a time. When writing your own xxxxx, it could be helpful to consider how much information you wish to encourage a reader to absorb before asking for more.

Comment: Colloquially these would be [*gobbets*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gobbet) of information, but that word doesn't fit your sentences; it's rather informal, I think.

Comment: I think the OP's own suggestion 'chunks' is reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

The initial chunk of information may be referred to as an ***abstract/synopsis/anecdotes***. Later, when the users want more information, they can read the full description of the article.

- *[abstract](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/abstract)* (noun)

  > Make a written summary of (an article or book)

  [ODO]
- *[synopsis](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/synopsis)*

  > A brief summary or general survey of something

  [ODO]

The particular web page that you have linked presents an ***abstract***/ a ***synopsis*** at the top and expands on it as per user's demand.

I'd use ***anecdotes*** rather cautiously in this context as it mainly deals with real life incidents.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the nature of the information, **point** may be appropriate. Among its many meanings is

> a single or separate article or item, as in an extended whole; a detail or particular

[Source: Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/point)

To use it in your case,

> A page on this site consists of multiple *points*, which will be presented to the user one at a time.
>   When writing your own *points*, it could be helpful to consider how much information you wish to encourage a reader to absorb before asking for more.

Points has many meanings, so at times it might be less clear or ambiguous but it can be used to address singular concepts being addressed.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider the term "[packet](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/packet)".  It has a meaning related to electronic data transfer.  It might possibly be too technical for your application though.

> a short fixed-length section of data that is transmitted as a unit in an electronic communications network

Comment: This has a conflicting meaning for websites, where data is delivered at a low level in packets. The connotation also leans toward the ensemble of information, where someone might refer to a group of papers as a packet.

Answer (score 1):

*Slide* is commonly used, and borrows from the PowerPoint concept, which itself borrowed from the slide projector.

Answer (score 1):

As Wiktionary has it "SNIPPET" means a small part of something — song, programme or sample.

*From the snippet I heard of the rehearsal, they sound pretty good.

So we may try SNIPPET in the present context. However, we have another most familiar and commonly used word, CLIPPING. EXCERPT is not bad either.

Comment: I did mention that in my answer.

Comment: @NVZ Of course you did; remove episode, dwell at length on it,I would upvote it.Simply, bring it to the fore.

Answer (score 0):

**Snippet** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snippet)

> *noun* a small part, piece, or thing; especially a brief quotable passage
>   *"snippets from the author's newest novel"*
>   *"read them a snippet of his latest poem"*

Answer (score 0):

**Episode** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/episode)

> *noun* 2. Each of the separate instalments into which a serialized story or radio or television programme is divided
>   *"the final episode of the series"*